# Strapi App Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: reactjs, deployment, strapi

I created an ecomerce with reactjs and strapi. This is first time using strapi I did watching an tutorial in youtube. When I try to fetch data,from my strapi app in my local computer everything works fine.But I created another strapi an in a VPS and deployed,I get this error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()/products?populate=*&[filters][type][$eq]=featured:1